# How to scale PNG image until reaches the target file size

Tags: java, bufferedimage

As the title says I'm trying to resize a PNG image in order to reach a target file size (in terms of MegaBytes).
I searched a lot on SO and over the web, found a lot of codes but all of them are not taking in consideration the final file size.
I've arranged some code but trying to optimize performance.

---

Example:

- Source image dimensions = 30 MB
- Target file output size = 5 MB

Current flow:

- 1 - Load the PNG image as `BufferedImage`
- 2 - Recursively use `Scalr.resize(...)` in order to resize the image

  - 2.1 - For each step use `ImageIO.write` to store the compressed PNG on a temporary file
  - 2.2 - Check the size using `File.length`, if size on disk is > 5 MB return to step 2
- 3 - Save the image using `ImageIO.write(...)`

This method works, fine-tuning some parameters (such as scale factor) I'm able to accomplish the task.

I'm trying to understand if I can improve all by calculating/guessing the final file size without storing the image on a temporary file.
There is a `byte[]` obj stored into the `BufferedImage` obj that I can get using `BufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer()` that represents the content of the image but obviously the size of this array is 2x o 3x bigger than the final size of the file because of the PNG compression algo.

I've tried some formula in order to calculate the value, something like:
`w * h * bitDepth * 8 / 1024 / 1024` but I'm sure that I'm loosing a lot of data and the accounts do not add up!

---

At the moment I'm using mainly this code:

```java
static void resize(BufferedImage image, String outPath, int scalingFactor) throws Exception {
    image = Scalr.resize(image, image.getWidth() - scalingFactor);

    // image.getData().getDataBuffer() - the byteArray containing image

    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("" + System.currentTimeMillis(), ".png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", tempFile);

    System.out.println("Calculated size in bytes is: " + tempFile.length() + " - factor: " + scalingFactor);

    // MAX_SIZE defined in bytes
    if (tempFile.length() > MAX_SIZE) {
        // recursion starts here
        resize(image, outPath, chooseFactor(tempFile, 4));
    } else {
        // break the recursive cycle
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outPath));
    }
}

static int chooseFactor(File image, int scale) {
    // MEGABYTE is 1024*1024
    double mbSize = (double) image.length() / MEGABYTE;
    return (int) ((mbSize / scale) * 100);
}
```

---

**There is a way to calculate/guess the final file size starting from `BufferedImage` object?**

Please tell me if I have made myself clear or can I give additional information.
Also recommend a more appropriate title for the question if you think it is not explanatory enough.

Thanks.

Comment: For better image quality resize the original instead of the temp file.

Comment: Oh you're right, thank you so much for the advice!

Comment: Change the scale strategy to look at file size and have a few rough scales predefined. If those doesn't work try a higher scale depending on the temp file size after last rescale.

Comment: Yes I had already thought about doing some massive tests on sets of images of different sizes to get the basic scale factors.
Eventually I will integrate the results into the thread :)

Answer (score 1):

Any monotone function along image width/height can be used to perform a binary search.

> This approach will work well for many changes that may be needed
> (changing from PNG to JPG, adding compression, changing optimization
> targets) versus an ad-hoc solution such as directly predicting the
> size of a PNG (which, for example, could simply change depending on
> what library is installed on your production servers or on the client
> that your application uses).

The stored bytes is expected to be monotone (anyway my implementation is safe [but not optimal] under no monotonic functions).

This function perform a binary search **to the lower domain** (e.g. not upscale the image) using any function:

```
static BufferedImage downScaleSearch(BufferedImage source, Function<BufferedImage, Boolean> downScale) {

    int initialSize = Math.max(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    int a = 1;
    int b = initialSize;

    BufferedImage image = source;
    while(true) {
        int c = (a + b) / 2 - 1;

        // fix point
        if(c <= a)
            return image;

        BufferedImage scaled = Scalr.resize(source, c);
        if(downScale.apply(scaled)) {
            b = c;
        } else {
            // the last candidate will be the not greater than limit
            image = scaled;
            a = c;
        }
    }
}
```

if we are interested in the final **PNG** file size, the search function will be the **PNG** size:

```
static final Path output = Paths.get("/tmp/downscaled.png");

static long persistAndReturnSize(BufferedImage image) {
    if(ImageIO.write(image, "png", output.toFile()))
        return Files.size(output);
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot write PNG file!");
}
```

(you could persist to memory instead filesystem).

now, we can generate images with size no more than any fixed value

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Paths.get("/home/josejuan/tmp/test.png").toFile());

    for(long sz: asList(10_000, 30_000, 80_000, 150_000)) {
        final long MAX_SIZE = sz;
        BufferedImage bestFit = downScaleSearch(image, i -> persistAndReturnSize(i) >= MAX_SIZE);
        ImageIO.write(bestFit, "png", output.toFile());
        System.out.println("Size: " + sz + " >= " + Files.size(output));
    }

}
```

with output

```
Size: 10000 >= 9794
Size: 30000 >= 29518
Size: 80000 >= 79050
Size: 150000 >= 143277
```

**NOTE:** if you do not use compression or you admit an approximation, probably you can replace the `persistAndReturnSize` function by an [estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator) without persist the image.

**NOTE:** our search space is `size = 1, 2, ...` but you could perform a similar search using more parameters like compression level, pixel color space, ... (although, probably, your domain then will be not monotone and you should use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent or similar).

Comment: First of all thank you for your time. I tried the code, it seems to work - very well. It is another implementation but still similar to mine. Even if basing on the tests I've done it seems that your solution is less performing than my solution - BUT seems to be more accurate (the final size is way more near to MAX_SIZE). Can I ask more clue about estimators? Do you have any resource to share or info about that? Again thanks

Comment: An estimator gives you a value quickly by guaranteeing that `P{bad result} < ε` and they are based on empirical values. Its correct use is strongly coupled to the context (eg. the library used!). For example, if it is very important to minimize the number of conversions to PNG (which I don't think), you can estimate the size (and quality of the estimate!) Based on experience. In this graph for diabetes you can see how the confidence in the value of the estimator varies https://laptrinhx.com/modelling-binary-logistic-regression-using-r-research-oriented-modelling-and-interpretation-2547280816/